# I can't connect using this connection in Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Hi I'm using this approach to connect to my system I'm using CPANEL.
but it seems it doesn't work. but when using xampp/localhost it's working.

hope you can help me to fix this thanks.

```
class db {
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "sample";
    private $password = "12345";
    private $dbname = "test";

/*connection*/
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    // 
    private function connect() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->servername,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $conn;
    }

    private function __clone() { }

    public function getConnection() {
        return db::connect();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get error message? Do you have database actually created in your cPanel?

Comment: @S.I. yes I configure it. no display that's it.

Comment: Did you try with simple connection not with class: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_proc

Comment: the class is working on cpanel if there's no connection involve in the function.

Answer (score 0):

According to cPanel the dbname and dbuser will have a  prefix of cpanel account name.

for instance if your cpanel account name is **myaccount** and your dbname is **mydb** and db user is **myuser** then ,

DB name for connection is

> myaccount_mydb

DB user for connection is

> myaccount_myuser

Kindly check your **"Mysql Databases"** page in your cPanel for more details

Hope this helps you